# How to sort numbers from largest to smallest?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to sort numbers from largest to smallest, but I didn't manage to do it.

My code sorted numbers with `5` digits perfectly but not the rest.

here is an example:

```
15366   
13070       
13069       
13068   
13067       
13066       
13065       
13064
313883
313880
313878
313876
313874
313872
313870
313869
313868
```

[image]

The result should be:

```
313883
313880
313878
313876
313874
313872
313870
313869
313868  
15366   
13070       
13069       
13068   
13067       
13066       
13065       
13064
```

I don't understand why it doesn't sort everything at once?

template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let transfer of transferResponse.PRE">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let preptf of transfer.PREPTF">
      <tr>
         ...
         <td class="text-center">
            <a [routerLink]="['/transfers/customer-transfer-details/' + preptf.NUM]">{{preptf.NUM }} </a>
         </td>
         ...
      </tr>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

interface

```
export interface TransferResponse extends ApiResponse {
    PRE: Transfer[];
}

export interface Transfer {
    DEPO: number;
    CLER: string;
    INTITULE1: string;
    PHONE: string;
    PREPTF: {
        LABEL: string;
        TYPE: string;
        QUANTITE: number;
        STATUT: number; 
        NUM: number;
        ISIN: string;
        STATUT_LIB: string;
        REF_RBC: string;
    }[];
}
```

composent

```
export class OverviewTransfersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();
   currentAgency: any;
   transferResponse: TransferResponse;

   constructor(
      private service: OverviewTransfersService,
      private store: Store,
      private modalService: BsModalService,
      private router: Router


   ) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.currentAgency = this.store.selectSnapshot(AgencyState.currentAgency);
      if (this.currentAgency) {
         this.OverviewTransfers();
      }
   }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.unsubscribe$.next();
      this.unsubscribe$.complete();
   }

   OverviewTransfers(): void {
      console.log('Before the request service.OverviewTransfers()');
      this.service.OverviewTransfers().pipe(
         takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe(res => {
         console.log('Response service.OverviewTransfers()', res);
         if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
            const transferResponse = res as TransferResponse;
            console.log('Before sorting', transferResponse);
            transferResponse.PRE.forEach(transfer => {
               transfer.PREPTF.sort((a, b) => {
                  return b.NUM - a.NUM;
               });
            });
            console.log('After sorting', transferResponse);
            this.transferResponse = transferResponse;
         }
      });
   }

}
```

**console.log**

[image]

**Response service.OverviewTransfers()**

[image]

**Before sorting service.OverviewTransfers()**

[image]

**After sorting service.OverviewTransfers()**

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: are you sure about `NUM`'s type ? You actually typed it as a number, but does the API really sends you a number ? If it is a string, `b.NUM - a.NUM` may have a strange behavior.

Comment: @Random, `NUM` is a `number` even in the API.

Comment: can you try doing the sort stuff inside the subscribe (in `OverviewTransfers()`) ? You should actually only sort your array once, and here you are sorting it again and again. That may help debugging.

Comment: @Random, Ah ok, I am sorry, I edited my first message. If you have a solution, I am interested.

Comment: Mattew figured it out. You cannot sort multiple arrays separately. First merge all these arrays together, then sort it, then display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are sorting an array inside an array.

First you have an array of `TransferResponse`, on which you are iterating to sort the sub array `PREPTF`.

If you want to do that, you will need to regroup all the numbers in a single array and then sort them.